# vim custom pop up menu

Tags: vim, autocomplete

How do I create a custom completion pop up menu.

I would like to be able to begin typing a part of a string then press a custom key combination to bring up a pop up completion of just a certain group of strings.

I already have omni complete set up and do not want to add to that list.

For example I have the list:
spo
spe
spa
I would like to be able to type sp then press ctrl+> and have a completion box come up for just that specific list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  inoremap <F5> <C-R>=ListMonths()<CR>

    func! ListMonths()
      call complete(col('.'), ['January', 'February', 'March',
            \ 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September',
            \ 'October', 'November', 'December'])
      return ''
    endfunc
```

Found it! Tucked away in that Grimoire they are trying to tell us are docs =)

======================= My final script is something like

```
inoremap <F5> <C-R>=CustomComplete()<CR>

        func! CustomComplete()
                echom 'move to start of last word'
                normal b
                echom 'select word under cursor'
                let b:word = expand('<cword>')
                echom '->'.b:word.'<-'
                echom 'save position'
                let b:position = col('.')
                echom '->'.b:position.'<-'
                normal e
                normal l
                echom 'move to end of word'     

                let b:list = ["spoogle","spangle","frizzle"]
                let b:matches = []


                echom 'begin checking for completion'
                for item in b:list
                echom 'checking '
                echom '->'.item.'<-'      
                        if(match(item,'^'.b:word)==0)
                        echom 'adding to matches'
                        echom '->'.item.'<-'      
                        call add(b:matches,item)
                        endif
                endfor
                call complete(b:position, b:matches)
                return ''
        endfunc
```

Comment: I dare you to find any documentation as complete as the Vim documentation though.

Comment: Vim is madness. Complete insanity what you can do with it.

Answer (score 4):

Create a list of words: `$HOME/wordlist` and add the dictionary to vim.

```
:set dictionary+=$HOME/wordlist
```

Activate the word list:

```
:set complete-=k complete+=k
```

Now you can autocomplete the words with `<CTRL>-P` and `<CTRL-N`

**Edit:** To have separate word lists, you create multiple lists, e.g.

```
$HOME/firstlist
$HOME/secondlist
```

and assign key bindings to pick a particular work list:

```
noremap <F5> :set dictionary=$HOME/firstlist<CR>:set complete-=k complete+=k<CR>
noremap <F6> :set dictionary=$HOME/secondlist<CR>:set complete-=k complete+=k<CR>
```

This has the advantage that you can use the `<CTRL>-P` and `<CTRL>-N` shortcuts as you're used to, once you picked the desired list.

Comment: Can I have separate dictionaries though? I would like a hot key for only a specific list. I am already using a dictionary.

Comment: @JamesAndino I updated my answer.